# MySQL Text Column Within String

Tags: mysql

This is the opposite of the popular question using LIKE %query%.  Is there a way to search for an occurrence of a text column value within a supplied string?

ie:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE %column_name_value% IN 'long text string here'
```

In the above, column_name_value equal to 'text string' should match.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  One method uses basically the same logic, just in reverse:

```
where 'long text string here' like concat('%', column_name_value, '%')
```